# Microsoft Sync for Ado.Net - efficiency, how to improve it?

Tags: synchronization, compact-framework, microsoft-sync-framework

Today I have finally managed to run client(windows mobile device) - wcf - sql server 2008 synchronization (after many problems, mostly for MS part)

I did test. For 24 000 records the average time for the snapshot takes about 1 minute 20 seconds. It is the time after I have downloaded the fix for Microsoft Sync for ADO.NET.

I have also discovered that after 50 seconds the database file finally starts to grow and it takes about 25 seconds.

What is the framework doing for the first 50 seconds? Loading and serializing data?

On some page, I found the article about surrogate serialization which can decrease the amount of data being transferred.

Do you know if the synchronization process might benefit from this? (I mean for MS Sync for Ado.net after hotfix?)

Is there anything I can do to speed up the process? In my opinion 1:24 for 24000 is twice too much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major issues with the synchronization framework for devices:

1. it exchanges data via ADO.NET Datasets
2. there is a lot of overhead involved on the client side to setup the client database for synchronization support on an "initial" synchronization.
3. SQL CE is very slow when it comes to inserts.

The hot fix you mentioned addresses #3 as best as it can, so there isn't much else you can do there.

number 2 is part of the synchronization framework, and there is nothing to be done about it i'm afraid.

As for #1, this is where much of that 50 seconds (perhaps 30 or so?) is being used: when the client receives the dataset, it must de-serialize the entire stream (where the stream consists of extremely verbose XML) before processing can begin. For large datasets (10,000+ rows) this can take a long time, and can (and will eventually) even lead to Memory Crunch scenarios once available heap memory is maxed out.

The serialization surrogate method you reference will substantially decrease the size of the response stream being exchanged (in my testing, it was almost 90% smaller in some cases). This will definitely improve response times somewhat, especially when the network connection throughput is limited. However, at the end of the day you can't get around the fact that that stream must be de-serialized into a DataSet before client side processing can begin.

All that to say: yes, the surrogate serialization method WILL decrease the amount of data being transferred, and you are likely to realize some improvement, but how much will depend on factors such as:

- size of the dataset
- amount of available device memory
- device processor speed and availability

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can the sync process really lead to "out of memory" issues on device? To be honest I thought that the framework is "ready" for such large data to be transferred into sql ce (or maybe I was naive thinking so..), well my original sync hand-crafted process, makes several calls to get portions of data because of deserialization issues I had run into... By the way, inserts to sql ce in "direct mode" are pretty fast, there is also on codeplex a class for bulk inserting which seems to be ultra fast...

Comment: Yes, it certainly can lead to OOM conditions. Depending on the count of rows and the width of each row etc, but at some point you will hit it. Keep in mind that each process is allocated a max of 32MB to work with. Additionally, depending on the OS you're using (WM6.1 and above have mitigated this somewhat), a lot of that memory is used by required system libraries.

Comment: eh Sometimes I really think that it would be better if I prepared an sdf file with bigger tables on server side and just upload it on mobile device.... Anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: yep, that's the way many of our apps work if bi-directional synchronization is not required.

Comment: I managed to go down with surrogate serialization from 1:20 to 0:40s. It is a gap :)

Answer (score 1):

Three things happen when you sync:
1. it needs to enumerate changes that has occured

1. it needs to send it to the destination
2. it needs to apply it

for enumeration, the size of the database will have a big impact. and you also incur some performance penalty for this checking even if there are no changes.

see : [Synchronization Services for ADO .NET for Devices: Improving performance by skipping tables that don’t need synchronization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/03/02/synchronization-services-for-ado-net-for-devices-improving-performance-by-skipping-tables-that-don-t-need-synchronization.aspx)

for item #2, dataset serialization is the bottleneck. You may opt to use Dataset surrogates or even compression, but there you get hit doing the surrogate and doing compression and you might not see massive performance improvements.

see: [Sync Framework WCF-based Synchronization for Offline scenario – Using custom dataset serialization](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/sync-framework-wcf-based-synchronization-for-offline-scenario-%E2%80%93-using-custom-dataset-serialization/)

for items 1 and 2, you may apply the same performance tuning you do for databases like synching only the rows you need via filtering, tuning index, etc...

After all, Sync Fx app is just like any other database app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SyncFx 2.1 libraries (SynchOrchestrator not SyncAgent) then SyncFx will already be using DataSet Surrogate serialization - it is built-in.

To avoid DataSet-related out-of-memory issues, you can take a look at batching to find ways to limit the number of records that can be sent per sync. It can be done to some extent with either set of SyncFx libraries, but is a bit more deterministic* with the 2.1 libraries than the 1.0 libraries.

> *deterministic: 
>   The 2.1 libraries allow you to specify a maximum number of bytes,
>   SyncFx will automatically cut things off at the last full row that fits inside that
>   limit. With the 1.0 libraries, I believe, the only way to
>   do batching is to specify a maximum row count, and hope (or calculate carefully) that the data
>   doesn't exceed the limit you want to achieve.

Comment: Right, that was my previous Sync version and well I disappointed when I realised that It will not run on WM.